# Java в gradle task

Tags: java, gradle

Мне нужно сделать несколько действий:

1. Собрать jar (можно сделать через зависимости)
2. Пропустить jar через ProGuard (таск уже есть. также делается через зависимости)
3. "Свалить" мою ProGuard jar'ку и все зависимости(либы) в одну папку *(plz help)*
4. Вычислить md5 всех файлов, запаковать их в json и отправить на сервер с файлами из 4 пункта.

Для последнего пункта у меня есть отдельный jar, при запуске с нужными параметрами которого я получаю всё то, что мне нужно. Осталось только попросить Gradle выполнить мой jar с его параметрами.
Как это сделать?

PS как реализовать 3 пункт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Третий пункт:
[Copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) позволяет копировать указанные файлы в нужную папку:

```
task initConfig(type: Copy) {
    from('proguard') {
        include '**/my.jar'
    }
    from('libs') {
        include '**/*.jar'
    }
    into 'target'
}
```

Запуск jar:
Для запуска jar есть [JavaExec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html):

```
task send_md5(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = '/path/to/send_md5.jar'
  main = 'send_md5.Main'
  // параметры
  args 'tramparam'
}
```